# Get php script directory name which works on all servers

Tags: php

I have an index.php file located in the path: http://www.example.com/inc/index.php

now i need to get the path till inc directory like http://www.example.com/inc/

This is the line i wrote in index.php

```
'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/'
```

It is working in apache server. It is not working in my client system. He is not sure about which server he is using, but told something other than apache.

Any input is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: lol.. just request him to explore what he is using..

Comment: You seriously need to think about a thing called "relative paths"

Answer (score 1):

This will give,

http://www.example.com/inc/

```
 <?php

     echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/';

 ?>
```

Actually, what is not working?  If you are not getting the index page loaded by  http://www.example.com/inc/ means, index.php is not set as default in the server.  If it is IIS server i think, the default page is index.html, default.html, default.asp - please check this, not index.php

for further reading,

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473251/Index-or-Default.htm

Answer (score 0):

The dirname function is looking at the file system. If you're trying to parse the URL to get to the directory, I suggest you use something like this:

```
$pathComponents = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
array_pop($pathComponents);
$dirName = implode('/', $pathComponents) . '/';
```

This should return 'inc/'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']? Just note that on Apache 2, this is not explicitly set (need a config setting). See here: [PHP $_SERVER manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

This appears to me that it may help you, but I do not have access to my httpd.conf file at my hosting space to confirm.

Hope this helps!

Kobus